# Cant add attachment to C# email

Tags: c#, outlook

I seem to be struggling to get the following code to work.  If i use the code below it suggests the file doesn't exist even though its just been created (and i can see it in explorer.

```
string path = @"LicenceFile.stslic";
File.WriteAllText(path, LicenceKey.ToString() + ";" + CRCValue + ";" + dateExpiry.Value.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy") );

Outlook.Application _app = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem)_app.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
mail.To = txtEmail.Text;

mail.Subject = "Your System Licence Key";
mail.Body = "Hello " + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "Please find attached your most recent licencing file for the use of the system." + Environment.NewLine + "Please tranfer this file to one of the STS machines." + Environment.NewLine + "Please double click on this file which should then return if the file has been installed succesfully." + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "Many Thanks" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "Me";
mail.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceHigh;
mail.ReadReceiptRequested = true;
mail.Attachments.Add((path));

((Outlook._MailItem)mail).Send();
```

Comment: You need to specify a full path, Outlook probably operates under it's own context with a different current path (I assume wherever the `outlook.exe` is)

Comment: "licensing" ...

Comment: Thanks very much, so I changed
`code` string path = @"LicenceFile.stslic";`code`
to
`code`string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"LicenceFile.stslic";`code`

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation for [`Attachments.Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.attachments.add?view=outlook-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Outlook_Attachments_Add_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_):

> `Source` Object
>
> The source of the attachment. This can be a file (represented by the full file system path with a file name) or an Outlook item that constitutes the attachment.

`string path = @"LicenceFile.stslic";` is a relative path, not a full file system path.

Answer (score 0):

The mail.Attachments.Add() method has four parameters, you can refer to the following code.

mail.Attachments.Add(path, Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue, 1, path);

The path parameter can be a file (represented by the full file system path with a file name) or an Outlook item that constitutes the attachment. Can refer to the following code example

```
string path = @"C:\Users\v-zhzhen\Desktop\study notes\exchange.docx";
            string str = "sadie@contoso.com";
            Outlook.Application _app = new Outlook.Application();
            Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem)_app.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
            mail.Subject = "Your System Licence Key";
            mail.Body = "Hello " + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "Please find attached your most recent licencing file for the use of the system." + Environment.NewLine + "Please tranfer this file to one of the STS machines." + Environment.NewLine + "Please double click on this file which should then return if the file has been installed succesfully." + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "Many Thanks" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "Me";
            mail.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceHigh;
            mail.ReadReceiptRequested = true;
            MessageBox.Show(path);
            if (path.Length > 0)
            {
                mail.Attachments.Add(path, Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue, 1, path);
            }
            mail.To = str;
            mail.Display();
            ((Outlook._MailItem)mail).Send();
```